# why am I getting text of all the links instead of one that is clicked by .text() function

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on the A1-810 or A1-820 Link.

**Output Comes Like this**

A1-810

ICONIA A-SERIES
A1-810
A1-820

**Now the HTML** Nav links are a little complicated actually there are more than 200 links in the navbar but I have copied a little code so that you can understand.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).text();
    console.log(a)
    return;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA A-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">A1-810</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">A1-820</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA B-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">B1-710</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">B1-720</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">LIQUID</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="">A1-S100</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Z200</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: .text() will take all the text of the children nodes until the matching `</li>` and will contain the nested UL's text too

Comment: `$(this).text()` contains _all_ the text inside `this`, including its children's text

Comment: Also your HTML in invalid. You have some stray `</div>` in there

Comment: you can use class on `<li><a href="#" class="links">A1-810</a></li><li><a href="#" class="links">A1-820</a></li>` and target that class like `$(".links").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).text();
    console.log(a)
    return;
  });`

Comment: @MShoaibQureshi If that li has children, the class will not make any difference

Comment: Beacause when you click the A1-810 It lies in <li>, but this <li> itself lies in its parent <li>, and hence that parent is also clicked. if you can notice the console.log shows formatted output. Its because its also rendering the html from parent <li> to the all its children

Comment: That is because the event handler is on the LI instead of the A

Comment: The class I have actually put on <a>.

Comment: In your code, you have targeted `<li>` which happen to be multilevel. so actually you are also targeting the parent (non-link) `<li>` as well.

Comment: I have added explanation in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229378/discussion-between-m-shoaib-qureshi-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I cannot change classes because I have 2100 <a> tags in my navbar so I wanted a generalized solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach the event listener to the LI instead of the A

The LI.text() will show all children of that LI

When you attach to the A instead the content of the clicked anchor is shown also use preventDefault so the link is not followed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-unstyled a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
    var a = $(this).text();
    console.log(a)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA A-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">A1-810</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">A1-820</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">ICONIA B-SERIES</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="#">B1-710</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#">B1-720</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">LIQUID</a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href="">A1-S100</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Z200</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Its because when you click the A1-810 It lies in `<li>`, but this `<li>` itself lies in its parent `<li>`, and hence that parent is also clicked. if you can notice the console.log shows formatted output. Its because its also rendering the html from parent `<li>` to the all its children

Here is how you can target only one thats clicked.

```js
$(".links").click(function() {    
var a = $(this).text();     
console.log(a)  ;  
return;   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" class="links">A1-810</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="links">A1-820</a></li>
```

Comment: wish we could know the reason for every down vote so that we can understand how to improve our answers.